# Jasmine expect toThrow not passing nor catching

Tags: javascript, exception, jasmine, promise, protractor

#### Trying to use `expect(fn).toThrow()` in protractor.

The function `(fn)` I'm passing returns a promise (`protractor.promise.defer`) which protractor supposedly forces `expect()` to deal with properly.

#### Upon running, instead of catching the error and/or passing the test, it does *neither*.

- "Expected function to throw an error"
- "Wait timed out after ~3000ms"

  - (Thrown by `browser.wait()`'s timeout parameter)

#### I have tried using:

- `deferred.reject()` which throws a catchable error

  - Normally caught by using `.thenCatch()` instead of `.then()` on a promising function
- `deferred.fulfill()` and throwing an error in the function "manually"

  - Using syntax `throw new Error();`
  - and `throw {name: 'Error', message: 'timed out'}`
  - and `throw {name: 'Exception'}`
- I have tried removing `.fulfill()` and `.reject()`, meaning the only way for the expect to move on is for the error to get thrown.
- I have even removed all `return` statements, so that the `expect` won't finish the function unless it throws the error.
- *Update*: tried using `.toThrowError()` instead of `.toThrow()`
- *Update*: tried override `.toThrow()` via custom matchers, but I have no idea how to make the anonymous function in `.thenCatch()` make the original matcher return its `result` object without returning a promise.

**Everytime** the expect fails *and* the error is still thrown and uncaught (exactly as the syntax says it will be thrown).

#### My hunches are:

- Is protractor not overriding `expect` properly for this case?
- Is it because the `throw` happens in an anonymous function passed to a `.then(function(){ /*error thrown here*/ })` and not the original `fn` function?
- Can I make a jasmine custom matcher return a promise to return the result later? (Does protractor account for those promises too?) Then I would just override the original `.toThrow()` method to account for the possibility.
- Or am I just overlooking something *that* simple?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your promise will be fulfilled/rejected later in time (async), you can't rely on the `expect(function() {..}.toThrow()` to work in that case.

What I would do is something like this (not used to protractor promises):

```
it('.....', function(done) {
    MyPromise(...)
        .then(... my normal process which should throw....)
        .then(function() { 
                   // Error not thrown by the process, so fail the test.
                   expect(true).toBe(false);
              },
              function(err) {
                   // Expected error thrown so pass the test.
                   done();
              });
});
```

Assuming this is how you catch errors with protractor promises ?

Some other implementation have a `.catch()` method you can chain.

Comment: `.thenCatch( function( error ) {} }` would be the syntax to use. I've thought about it, but it's such an ugly hack that does not lend itself to reusability. Using `expect(true).toBe(false)` provides no useful information to the test results.

Comment: It's really a hack, but how you have to handle async process unless protractor supplies customized async expectation ? regarding your 2nd point, what more information would you expect than the one you would get with the `expect().toThrow()` if your process did not throw an exception ? you can replace it with `expect(function() { return true}).toThrow()` if you want ?

Comment: Protractor just automagically forces the `actual` value inside the `expect( actual )` to be resolved before using the matcher, that's all it provides. Regarding my 2nd point, I realized I'm just being overly idealistic. It doesn't provide any useful extra information at the moment.

Comment: oups, i meant to say 'it's not a hack'. that's how you would handle async process which could fail later on in time. hence the usage of the done method. in the previous version of jasmine, you had to use the `run(...)` `waitFor(...)` combo... that was horrible to use with multiple async process... with a test case unreadable...

Answer (score 1):

[Chai as Promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised) might help to have a cleaner syntax, e.g. something like:

```
expect(fn_returning_promise()).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith(...)
```

Comment: I'll keep Chai in mind, but it's not worth switching from Jasmine for my purposes. In retrospect, I don't need `toThrow()` or promising matchers when I'm just checking for element presence (I just need to `thenCatch()` a timeout).